# How to run multiple long task method in the same time in Spring Boot Service?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, asynchronous

Here is my question, I have create a service class which handle upload the files to cloud from a output folder. inside this output folder, it will have large volume of files generate when trigger.

Below is my class of the Service.

```
     @Service
     Public class uploadService {
         
         public void UploadAllFile(String processCode) {

             if (processCode = "allfile") {

          1      //no need check generate status, start to upload while files generating
                 //keep upload files while generate process ongoing, until finish generate.
                 uploadPDF();

                  
          2      //check other type of files generate status, wait all finish just start upload.
                 ReadFileGenerateLog;
                 if (log.contain("txt") == "all finish generate") {
                       uploadTxt();
                 }
                 if (log.contain("xml") == "all finish generate") {
                       uploadXml();
                 }
             }
         }


         public void UploadPDF(){

         }

         public void UploadTxt(){

         }

         public void UploadXml(){

         }
     }
```

Now the problem is there will be few hundred PDF files need to be generate and upload, it will take 1 hour smtg to finish the whole process (uploading while still generating until finish). While other type of file is finish with 10 minutes (wait until finish generate and upload).

So based on my code logic, it is impossible to wait [1] function finish then just start [2] function. Is that anyway I can run both logic together instead waiting the first one to finish? Please teach me to solve this solution.

Comment: As always, there is no one solution. 
One possibility would be to use reactive streams. look here https://spring.io/reactive. One other solution would be to use Spring Batch.

Comment: Can you check ExecutorService in Java? You need a thread pool to manage limited number of threads to handle files.

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/java-executor-service-tutorial maybe this can help you

Comment: What about CompletableFuture? https://www.baeldung.com/java-completablefuture

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

for(int i = 0; i < FILE_COUNT; i++) {
   executor.submit(() -> {
      uploadPDF(i)
   })
}
```

Simply you can use ExecutorService to manage multi threaded upload PDF. You can also get result If you investigate https://www.baeldung.com/java-executor-service-tutorial

Comment: Okay, it is work!! sorry for reply so late. Thanks for your advice!!!!